# Vector field on the unit sphere

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, vector-analysis, vector-fields

Let $\vec\psi$ be the vector field defined on the unit sphere $S^2$ in the basis $(\vec e_r,\vec e_\theta,\vec e_\varphi)$ of spherical coordinates by:
$$\vec\psi(r=1,\theta,\varphi)=(0,\sin\varphi,0)$$
I want to determine the integral curves of $\vec\psi$.
So I solve the system $$\begin{cases}\dfrac{dr}{dt}=0\\ \dfrac{d\theta}{dt}=\sin \varphi \\ 
\dfrac{d\varphi}{dt}=0 \end{cases}$$
and the integral curves are given by: $r(t)=c_1$, $\varphi(t)=c_2$ and $\theta(t)=\sin(c_2)t+c_3$ where $c_1,c_2,c_3$ are any constant numbers.
Is this correct and is there any physical phenomena that can be described by such a vector field ?

Comment: Seems fine to me!

Comment: Now I think that the actual system to solve is $\begin{cases}  \dfrac{dr}{dt}=0\\ r\dfrac{d\theta}{dt}=\sin(\varphi) \\ r\sin(\theta)\dfrac{d\varphi}{dt}=0\end{cases}$